# Angular 5 - Routing test failed with Jasmine when try to navigate to a specific route

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, jasmine, angular5

I work with Angular 5, and I'm testing an angular service with Jasmine & Karma.
I have an authentication service with functions including a function that can redirect to the login page. I call it if the user is not authenticated.

I try this function, which doing a simple "router.navigate['login']", but I have the following error :

```
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0) AuthenticationService should redirect to login page FAILED
        Expected '' to be '/login'.
            at Object.<anonymous> home/user/Git/astre-fo/src/app/services/authentification.service.spec.ts:171:29)
            at Object.<anonymous> home/user/Git/astre-fo/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:411:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke home/user/Git/astre-fo/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke home/user/Git/astre-fo/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 17 of 17 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 1.922 secs)
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0) AuthenticationService should redirect to login page FAILED
        Expected '' to be '/login'.
            at Object.<anonymous> home/user/Git/astre-fo/src/app/services/authentification.service.spec.ts:171:29)
            at Object.<anonymous> home/user/Git/astre-fo/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:411:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke home/user/Git/astre-fo/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 17 of 17 (1 FAILED) (2.031 secs / 1.922 secs)
```

authentication.service.spec.ts :

```
import {AuthenticationService} from './authentification.service';
import {async, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {routes} from '../app.routes';
import {AppModule} from '../app.module';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';

describe('AuthenticationService', () => {

  let service: AuthenticationService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        UserService
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });

  it('should redirect to login page', fakeAsync(() => {

    service.redirectToLogin();

    tick(50);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
  }));

});
```

authentication.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    public userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  public redirectToLogin() {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

app.routes.ts :

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

**pass / it will work**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : use a promise !

```
  it('should redirect to login page', fakeAsync(() => {

    service.redirectToLogin().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
    });
  }));
```

If someone has a better solution, or if my solution is not the right one, let me know :)